# Combining 8 Tables into 1 query

Tags: sql, join

Hey im in over my head in a recent project i started.

I got 8 tables that needs to be joined so that all the tables content will get displayed with 1 single query

But im struggling to come up with the right query as im quite new to SQL

I have made a database diagram that shows which relationship the keys have to each other, don’t mind those that aren’t assigned an arrow that is just information.

[image: Diagram]

So basically I just want all the 8 tables joined in so a way that I via a php script can write eg.

$result = mysql_query(“SQL");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$id = $row["value"];
Of course I will be using some sort of loop to display multiply items

It will end out in multiply items on my frontpage that should be displayed by newest item from that category which I hope and assume is a simple where to the join.

But all in all, the thing im looking for is an SQL that joins the 8 tables with 1 query so that I can use any information from any of the 8 tables.

I think i found a working solution

```
SELECT *
FROM Deal d
INNER JOIN DealPrice dp ON d.Id = dp.DealId
LEFT JOIN DealMedia dm ON d.Id = dm.DealId
LEFT JOIN StorageFile sf ON dm.Id = sf.binId AND sf.name = 'original_t'
LEFT JOIN DealLocation dl ON d.Id = dl.dealid
LEFT JOIN Location l ON dl.location = l.id
LEFT JOIN DealCategoryAssoc dca ON d.Id = dca.DealId
LEFT JOIN DealCategory dc ON dca.CategoryId = dc.id
LEFT JOIN I18N i ON dc.id = i.relatedId AND i.model = 'DealCategory' AND i.language = 'da_dk'
```

I found out there is another table DealLocation that i didnt take into my diagram therefore i altered the code myself a little

Comment: My suggestion would be to post what you have written so far.  Here is a hint, you will want to join the tables on the related foreign keys - in your diagram this would be the columns with the arrows.  Once you have tried to write the query, if you get stuck then ask a question.

Comment: `so that i can use the data` What actually is the output you want. And instead of posting image please post schema and sample data with desired output.

Comment: This is a great example of why *not* to use a relational database.  See also [this video](http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2013/05/03/why-choose-nosql-and-document-databases-over-rdbms/) starting around 3:18.  Of course, I prefer RavenDB. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson I've never heard anyone suggest *not* to use a relational database before, which I find incredibly interesting. I'm going to check out the video you posted, might just learn something new. Is migrating away from RDBMs a thing of the future or has it been an ongoing conversation for some time now?

Comment: @MattJohnson I'm not sure why you think this is a case not to use a RDBMS, since this is very clearly **RELATIONAL DATA**...there are certainly times and reasons to use NoSQL or non-relational dbs but this isn't one of them.

Comment: Minor quibble: is this to be done in `mysql` or `mssql`?  It's tagged for both....

Comment: @JNK & all - Sorry, I didn't mean to troll.  All I'm saying is that this could probably be done in 1 document instead of 8 tables.  There is only one aggregate root here (the "Deal").  Perhaps one could argue that "Location" and "Category" deserve to be their own roots.  But still - this is only "relational" data because the relationships had to be created in order to fit it into tables.

Comment: @MattJohnson No it's relational because the entities in the related tables exist outside the particular incident.  This is a bigger discussion than we should have in comments here but there are reasons for both use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just identify the top entity (all the entities are pointing at it - deal)
Then join into all the related tables one after the other...

```
SELECT *
FROM Deal d
LEFT JOIN DealPrice dp ON d.Id = dp.DealId
LEFT JOIN DealMedia dm ON d.Id = dm.DealId
LEFT JOIN StorageFile sf ON dm.Id = sf.binId
LEFT JOIN Location l ON d.Id = l.Id
LEFT JOIN DealCategoryAssoc dca ON d.Id = dca.DealId
LEFT JOIN DealCategory dc ON dca.CategoryId = dc.id
LEFT JOIN i18N i ON dc.id = i.relatedId
```

Comment: Someone downvoted you for using `*` in your query. Read the other comments on the page, they explain why it is bad (even more here).

Comment: Well the OP didn't really explain what they were trying to get from the query so I didn't waste time performance tuning it based on a guess but ok...

Comment: Your query is working but as some of them got a one to many and many to one relationship there are alot of duplicates :)

Comment: Yes, the reason my answer returns too many results and the first answer none is because I use left joins and they use inner joins.  You need to use left joins where there may be no matches and inner joins where there must be a match.  So if a deal must always have a deal price you should use inner join DealPrice dp ON d.Id = dp.DealId but if deal sometimes does not have a dealprice use left join

Comment: Look like i solved my problem, i didnt make the DB myself so i found out there was another relationship. the query i found working
SELECT *
FROM Deal d
INNER JOIN DealPrice dp ON d.Id = dp.DealId
LEFT JOIN DealMedia dm ON d.Id = dm.DealId
LEFT JOIN StorageFile sf ON dm.Id = sf.binId AND sf.name = 'original_t'
LEFT JOIN DealLocation dl ON d.Id = dl.dealid
LEFT JOIN Location l ON dl.location = l.id
LEFT JOIN DealCategoryAssoc dca ON d.Id = dca.DealId
LEFT JOIN DealCategory dc ON dca.CategoryId = dc.id
LEFT JOIN I18N i ON dc.id = i.relatedId AND i.model = 'DealCategory' AND i.language = 'da_dk'

Answer (score 5):

I would use an `INNER JOIN` over a `LEFT JOIN` in this scenerio because a left join will return all records from the left table even when there are no matches in the right table, which I don't think you want - hard to tell from the question

[*Take a look at my favorite visual description of Joins*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

```
SELECT i18n.relatedid, 
       dealcategory.id, 
       dealcategoryassoc.dealid, 
       deal.location, 
       dealprice.pricevalue, 
       dealmedia.description, 
       location.city, 
       storagefile.extension, 
       storagefile.name, 
       storagefile.hash 
FROM   i18n 
       INNER JOIN dealcategory 
               ON i18n.relatedid = dealcategory.id 
       INNER JOIN dealcategoryassoc 
               ON dealcategory.id = dealcategoryassoc.categoryid 
       INNER JOIN deal 
               ON dealcategoryassoc.dealid = deal.id 
       INNER JOIN dealprice 
               ON deal.id = dealprice.dealid 
       INNER JOIN dealmedia 
               ON dealprice.dealid = dealmedia.dealid 
       INNER JOIN storagefile 
               ON dealmedia.id = storagefile.bindid 
       INNER JOIN location 
               ON deal.location = location.id
```

Comment: +1 For actually using column names

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Sorry about that, I've explained

Comment: I would +1 again for using the actual keys from the diagram if I could

Comment: @Evan no problem I saw that, deleted my comment and upvoted. I admire your patience ^_^

Comment: The thing is i get no data returned when using this query, im trying to combine it all so that i can use it for a frontpage view, since the image are uploaded via the website and the details are saved in I18N

+ price and value are two separate columns

Comment: I left alot of data out eg. some column name as i wanted to combine all the tables so that i got all information out via the relationships of the tables, i tried altering names and etc. but your query isnt outputting anything :/

Comment: @StaffanStormEnemark Open up a new question, but next time give the table schema, some sample data, and clearly explain what data you want from the query and someone will give you a much more exact solution that you can use. From what you've provided I've done the best that I can do.

Comment: +1 despite the link to that awful "description of joins."

Comment: @ypercube You've got another one? That was always the one that I went to

Comment: My point is that it's a wonderful description of Unions, Intersections and Differences. But certainly not of joins - as the author himself admits on comments.

Comment: @ypercube I wasn't being sarcastic :) If you have a better article, please post it. I just don't have any other ones bookmarked.

Answer (score -3):

You should read about [relationships between tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx). Now I don't want to give the whole solution but if you want *all data* from the tables to make a bigger table from the 8 you already have use Outer Join.

It would look like this (**This is pseudo code to show the basic syntax**).

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.table1Id
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.Id = t3.table2Id
LEFT JOIN Table4 t4 ON t3.Id = t4.table3Id
LEFT JOIN Table5 t5 ON t4.Id = t5.table4Id
LEFT JOIN Table6 t6 ON t5.Id = t6.table5Id
LEFT JOIN Table7 t7 ON t6.Id = t7.table6Id
LEFT JOIN Table8 t8 ON t7.Id = t8.table7Id
```

The syntax `ON` is where you use the `Primary Key` / `Foreign Key` to specify the relationship.

Comment: i didn't downvote ... but the select * on an eight table outer join will make for a fun result set.

Comment: 1 - You use `SELECT *`  2 - Your `JOIN`s are all invalid since you use table names with space and no delimiter   3 - should probably be `INNER` joins

Comment: `What I would like to end up with is all 8 tables combined so that I can use the data :)` he wants **all data**.

Comment: He wants to combine the tables, doesn't mean you need to use a left join ;) An inner join can combine the tables too, the difference being it does so only on matching records in both tables.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk And you'll be giving him at least 8 duplicate fields just on the join keys

Comment: @JNK Select * is correct. As for the table name.. my mistake ^^.
And Inner join could reject some records. Left Join won't. no matter what.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Select * is **NEVER CORRECT**.  Please point me to some resource somewhere that recommends this as a best practice.  At a minimum you can put `SELECT <columns>`.  The asker here is a SQL newbie, we probably should not be instilling the worst possible practices into them.

Comment: And yes, `INNER JOIN` will select non-matching records.  That's the point of an `INNER JOIN`.  You don't typically use a `LEFT JOIN` in a normalized model like this one.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk wouldn't you want unmatched "records" to be not be included?

Comment: @JNK OP asked for a way to get ALL data. No data left appart. So he could use the data from a single table. What I did was just put all data from his tables into a single one. Like he asked. Now as stated in my answer I don't want to give the whole answer since he obiviously didn't take a second to look around about how to do this. I pointed out key words and basic syntax. In that case Select * is correct. Even though I would never use it in a query. I would not use table names with numbers too.

Comment: @swasheck well no because I thought (and still think) that what OP wants is putting all data from his 8 tables into a single one. Since he doesn't understand what joins are or how they work, he would probably wonder where some of the data is gone because one of the field was null. (Since he asked for a solution where he could put **all data** in a single table). But don't worry I know that in his case, after reading the design and the tables I would use inner joins too.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Sorry, I guess my issue is, he gives you a diagram with table names and field names so there's no real reason to do it the way you did

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk partly it's just a problem with the breadth of the question since the OP obviously is not really sure what he wants.

Comment: @JNK Well my issue was he gave me a plan and asked me to code a query for him. So instead of downvoting and ignoring, I pointed out some keywords and explanation. But still I know my query is pseudo code and I would **never** use it. I should have pointed it out

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk in this case, unmatched records are not actually data.

Comment: @swasheck why is that ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Actually you'll leave some data out, too. Unless you convert the joins to `FULL` joins.